# How to give an attribute of a class the req.body values?

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, frontend

I have a class which is a controller that executes a method when it is called from a route, and I am trying to give my dataStore attribute within the list method (defining it of any type, because I don't know what other type it could put) , the object that in theory should give me `req.body.¿`?

This is being written in typescript, and requests are being sent through postman.

```
class RentController{
    private dataStore:any; 

    public search(req:Request, res:Response){
        this.dataStore= req.body; 
        res.send(this.dataStore);
    }
}
```

[Here is what i sent by postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkUrH.png)
[Here is what i recieved by postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cD0i1.png)

The error that throws me is:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'dataStore' of undefined

Comment: it's saying `this` is undefined here, console the value of `this`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler is confused by your use of `this` outside of any defined scope. Make sure you say `RentController.dataStore = req.body;`, assuming you are trying to assign `req.body` to the `dataStore` attribute of `RentController`.

Essentially, avoid using `this` in this situation, it is making things more complicated. If you are trying to use the parameter, use `req.dataStore` or `res.dataStore`, but try to avoid using `this`.

Comment: After doing `RentController.dataStore = req.body;` and put `dataStore` as `static`, this worked for me, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing your class members with any default value.
That's why it's default value is undefined.

try to assign any default value then check your result you will get that value.

```
class RentController{
    private dataStore:any = {value: 1}; 

    public search(req:Request, res:Response){
        this.dataStore= req.body; 
        res.send(this.dataStore);
    }
}
```